# My mediaqueries wont work even though i seperated it with its own stylesheet?

Tags: css

```html
<div class="row iex-reepay">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
<div class="after-element-pseudo"> 
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/sites/61/2018/10/iex-ikon-2.png" class="iex-icon"></div>
</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-2"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/sites/61/2018/10/iex-ikon-2.png" class="reepay-icon"></div>
</div>
```

I have made a pseudo-class after element which works fine without media-queries.
When i start working responsive with my media-queries something goes wrong. 
It seems like it only uses the after:element i made on large screen when media-queries is not needed.

I tried to separate my media-queries to their own stylesheet but the issue is still there. I tried to change a `img` size and nothing changes.
I really tried everything, validating my CSS etc.

```css
@media screen and (max-width:1199px) {
    .feature-icons-div {
        margin-right: 38px;
    }
    .after-element:after {
        content: "";
        width: 55px;
        height: 81px;
        background-size: 55px 19px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/sites/61/2018/10/arrow-after-element.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        vertical-align: middle;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 36px;
        right: -79px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:992px) {
    .reepay div#manage-subscribtion-section section#themo_service_block_split_1 {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 95px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
    .after-element {
        position: relative;
    }
    .after-element-pseudo:after {
        content: "";
        width: 55px;
        height: 81px;
        background-size: 55px 19px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/sites/61/2018/10/arrow-after-element.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        vertical-align: middle;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 36px;
        right: 42px;
    }
    img.reepay-icon {
        max-width: 93px;
    }
    img.iex-icon {
        max-width: 93px;
    }
    .iex-icons-div {
        margin-top: 45px;
    }
    .reepay h2 {
        color: #4f4f4f !important;
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    .reepay div#manage-subscribtion-section section#themo_service_block_split_1 {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 275px;
    }
    div#reepay-integeration-top section#themo_iex_block_visma_1 li p {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    div#reepay-integeration-top #themo_iex_block_visma_1 {
        padding-top: 145px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    .reepay h1 {
        font-size: 34px;
    }
    img.subscribtion-image {
        margin-top: 286px;
    }
    .reepay div#manage-subscribtion-section section#themo_service_block_split_1 {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 106px;
    }
    .reepay .split-blocks .service-block p {
        margin-left: 34px;
    }
    /*   
    .border-without-background-feature:after {
        content: "";
        width: 59px;
        height: 81px;
        background-size: 52px 19px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/sites/61/2018/10/arrow-after-element.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        vertical-align: middle;
        position: absolute;
        top: 129px;
        transform: rotate(89deg);
    } */
    .border-radius-for-iex:after {
        content: "";
        width: 59px;
        height: 81px;
        background-size: 52px 19px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/sites/61/2018/10/arrow-after-element.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        vertical-align: middle;
        position: absolute;
        right: 58px;
        transform: rotate(89deg);
        /* bottom: -111px; */
        top: 132px;
    }
    .iex-icons-div {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .border-radius-for-iex {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 120px;
        width: 120px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #fff;
        position: relative;
        /* margin: auto 0; */
        margin-left: 104px;
    }
    .border-without-background-feature {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 96px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:540px) {
    .reepay .split-blocks .service-block p {
        margin-left: 14px;
    }
    .reepay h1 {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    div#order-right-now .iex-btnn {
        background-color: #15d384;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 49px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 18px;
        border-radius: 26px;
    }
    .reepay h2 {
        color: #4f4f4f !important;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    div#order-right-now .iex-btnn {
        background-color: #15d384;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 60px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 18px;
        border-radius: 26px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    img.center-block.reepay-header-dashboard {
        padding-top: 35px;
        padding-right: 22px;
    }
    .reepay h1 {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    div#reepay-integeration-top section#themo_iex_block_visma_1 li p:before {
        content: "";
        width: 55px;
        height: 81px;
        background-size: 25px 19px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/sites/61/2018/10/arrow.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        vertical-align: middle;
        position: absolute;
        left: -19px;
        top: 6px;
    }
    div#reepay-integeration-top section#themo_iex_block_visma_1 li p {
        font-size: 17px;
    }
}
```

```css
/* This is for all the h1 on the site */

.reepay h1 {
    font-size: 37px;
}


/* This is for all the h2 on the site */

.reepay h2 {
    color: #4f4f4f !important;
}

div#reepay-integeration-top em {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 46px;
}


/* This is the header of the Reepay site start */

.reepay .navbar {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #0464ab !important;
}

.reepay .navbar .navbar-nav>li.active>a {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: initial;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.reepay html .navbar .navbar-nav>li>a:hover:after,
html .navbar .navbar-nav>li.active>a:after,
html .navbar .navbar-nav>li.active>a:hover:after,
html .navbar .navbar-nav>li.active>a:focus:after {
    bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

.reepay .navbar .navbar-nav>li.active>a,
.navbar .navbar-nav>li.active>a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav>li.active>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
}

.reepay .navbar-default {
    background-color: #0464ab;
    border-color: #0464ab;
}


/* This is the header of the Reepay site end */


/* Second section start */

div#reepay-integeration-top #themo_iex_block_visma_1 {
    padding-top: 96px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

div#reepay-integeration-top li p {
    margin-top: 12px;
}

div#reepay-integeration-top li {
    list-style: none;
}

div#reepay-integeration-top section#themo_iex_block_visma_1 li p {
    font-size: 23px;
}

div#reepay-integeration-top section#themo_iex_block_visma_1 li p:before {
    content: "";
    width: 55px;
    height: 81px;
    background-size: 25px 19px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/sites/61/2018/10/arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    left: -19px;
    top: 16px;
}

img.center-block.reepay-header-dashboard {
    padding-top: 35px;
}


/* This is the section for order now button  */

div#order-right-now .iex-btnn {
    background-color: #15d384;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 99px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 26px;
}

div#order-right-now section#themo_iex_brands_1 {
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}


/* This is the section of manage-subscribtion */

div#manage-subscribtion-section p {
    color: #4f4f4f;
    font-size: 19px;
}

img.manage-subscribtion-icons {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.reepay div#manage-subscribtion-section section#themo_service_block_split_1 {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}


/* Remove the borders that i cant remove from the backend, i thuink it gets shout out from somewhere else to all subsites */

.reepay .border-wrap.top .border {
    border-left: 2560px solid #e5e5e4;
    border-top: 70px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0 solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
    display: none;
}

.reepay .border-wrap.bottom .border {
    border-left: 2560px solid #e5e5e4;
    border-top: 0 solid;
    border-right: 0 solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 70px solid transparent;
    display: none;
}

.reepay section#themo_iex_testimonials_1 {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}


/* This is the service-block section */

div#service-block-for-glyphicons h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

div#service-block-for-glyphicons .service-blocks-horiz {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}


/* Feature page --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- */

div#feature-integeration-top section#themo_iex_block_visma_1 {
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

div#feature-integeration-top p {
    font-size: 23px;
}


/* manage subscribtion for feature */

.border-radius-for-iex img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 28px;
    top: 17px;
}

.border-radius-for-iex {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 120px;
    width: 200x;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}


/* after element for the manage subscribtion feature page */

.reepay section#themo_html_1 {
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 275px;
}

.inner-wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
    /* margin: auto 0; */
    text-align: center;
}

.remove-bullet li:before {
    content: "";
    width: 55px;
    height: 81px;
    background-size: 25px 19px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/sites/61/2018/10/Vector-Smart-Object-copy-3.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    left: -6px;
    /* top: 18px; */
}

.inner-wrapper p {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: -5px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #2083c2;
}

.remove-bullet li {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 9px;
}

.remove-bullet {
    list-style: none;
}

#fff .remove-bullet li {
    text-align: center;
}

.row.four-logo {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 24px;
}

img.uniconta {
    max-width: 200px;
}

img.billy {
    max-width: 190px;
}

img.dinero {
    max-width: 190px;
}

img.economic {
    max-width: 191px;
}

.row.iex-reepay {
    text-align: center;
}

.after-element-pseudo:after {
    content: "";
    width: 55px;
    height: 81px;
    background-size: 55px 19px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/sites/61/2018/10/arrow-after-element.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 36px;
    right: -61px;
}

.row.iex-reepay {
    position: relative;
}


/* This is the section for the media queries  */
```

Comment: What exactly "goes wrong"? Can you add html?

Comment: I can't see the responsive changes

Answer (score 0):

Did you use your separated media-queries CSS link after main style? You have to use all responsive code after main style to get priority.

Comment: I used it after the main style

Comment: Now it works, i dont know why, but i tried to cut it all and put it in again

Comment: Did you set meta viewport in head tag?
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">